# Remove Characters only from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL string and I need to remove the last characters (if it is only a A-Z),

> > Original : 001-123456AB
> >     Expected : 123456
> >
> > Original :001-123456
> >     Expected :123456

In here I  have get the 123456 portion. Now I need if this SQL string contains character then
need to remove

```
(SUBSTRING(GeoNews,0,CHARINDEX('-',GeoNews))
```

Comment: Any specific reason for `c#` tag?

Answer (score 3):

If alphabetic characters only appear at the end of the string and not in the middle, you can do:

```
select left(geonews, patindex('%[A-Z]%', geonews + 'A') - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
select reverse(substring(geonews, patindex('%[0-9]%', geonews), len(geonews))) from (
    select reverse(substring(geonews, charindex('-', geonews, 1) + 1, LEN(geonews))) geonews
    from my_table
) a
```

It takes part after hyphen `-`, reverses it, now "ending" letter will be at the beginning. We will remove it (with `substring` and `patindex`, which will return first occurence of a digit in a string) and then reverse the string back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = '001-123456AB'
WHILE (@String is not null and @String LIKE '%[a-Z]')
BEGIN  

-- Chop off the end character
   SET @String = 
         CASE LEN(@String) WHEN 0 THEN @String 
            ELSE LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) 
         END 
END  


SELECT right(@String, len(@String) - charindex('-', @String))
```

Comment: Ouch. This works but loops is generally something we want to avoid.